# Parsing dates using WTForms Flask - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, flask, flask-wtforms

Hi So I've been using WTForms with success for a good period of time now.

The problem is on how to parse dates.

I've always used to assign variables according to form data as follows

```
firstname = form.firstname.data
```

This will store the user's input from the form data into my variable called "firstname", which works just fine, my problem is when it comes to dates.

I have the following code

**WTForms Class**

```
class BookingForm(Form):
start_date = DateField('Start Date', format='%m/%d/%Y')
end_date = DateField('End Date', format='%m/%d/%Y')
```

**The booking route**

```
@app.route('/book/', methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def book():
try:
    form = BookingForm(request.form)

    if request.method == "POST" and form.validate():
        start_date = form.start_date.data
        end_date = form.end_date.data
        # I Have also tried form.start_date.data.strftime('%m-%d-%Y') with no luck
 ...
```

**The HTML Template {jinja}**

```
<div class="col-md-4">
     {{ render_date_field(form.start_date) }}
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
     {{ render_date_field(form.end_date) }}
</div>
```

I am also using datetime in python

```
from datetime import datetime
```

I've been trying to follow many docs on how to parse a date into a variable from a user input form with no luck, Does anybody know the right syntax?

Thanks

Comment: The date format specified must be enforced when your form is filled in the browser. Your date format is '__%m/%d/%Y__'. An example date for start date using this format is __10/06/2018__. This is parsed by `wtf` as __2018-10-06__ and stored in `form.start_date.data`

Answer (score 1):

`form.date_created.data` returns a `datetime.date` object.

The `month`, `day`, and `year` attributes store these values as integers. There is no need to import the `datetime` to solve this problem.

You can use `date.strftime('%m-%d-%y')` to get a string representation such as `"10-22-18"`.

```
form = BookingForm(request.form)  
if request.method == "POST" and form.validate():
    start_date = form.start_date.data
    end_date = form.end_date.data

    # print(type(start_date))   -> <class 'datetime.date'>

    start_month = start_date.month
    start_day = start_date.day
    start_year = start_date.year

    start_date_str = start_date.strftime('%m-%d-%y')
    # and so on...
```

Take a look at the [WTForms Documentation](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6.1/fields.html#basic-fields) for DateField.

```
class wtforms.fields.DateField(default field arguments, format='%Y-%m-%d')
        Same as DateTimeField, except stores a datetime.date.
```

You can check out more about the `date` object in the docs
[Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#date-objects)

*Tip*: if you had tried `print(type(start_date))` to see what it prints, you probably would have figured it out on your own.

Comment: I've tried using " print(type(start_date)) " but I'm getting None in return and obviously the flask eror is " must be string or read-only buffer, not None " Thanks for your help

Comment: If `state_date` is `None` then it sounds like you are not getting the form data to begin with. Parsing is not your issue. Two things you can do:   
_(1)_ Look into using something like [pdb](https://realpython.com/python-debugging-pdb/) or [flask-debugtoolber](https://flask-debugtoolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to figure out where stuff went wrong.
_(2)_ Another place to check is in the dev tools of your browser in the _Network_ tab, to see that the POST request is being made with the expected request parameters.

Comment: Ok found out I had a typo and got it fixed... thanks for your help, on another note, do you recommend using an html date-time picker to store dates in a database or just a textfield with a jquery layer on top?